# Экспортирование из DLL функции, которая содержит аргумент, тип которого является псевдонимом, определенным в namespace или class

Tags: c++, dll, export

Подскажите, пожалуйста, позволено ли в `C++` следующее:

```
namespace N
{
    class C
    {
        public:
        using Callback_t = void (*)(uint8_t*, size_t);
    };
};

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) void cdecl function(N::C::Callback_t callback)
{
    // ...
}
```

Я имею в виду, будет ли использоваться элементарный тип `void (*)(uint8_t*, size_t)`, или же имя типа будет подвержено искажению?

Comment: В скомпилированной динамической библиотеке вообще не будут имена типов, только имена функций и возможно размер принимаемых параметров (типа `function@4`).

Comment: Не будет никаких типов, только имя функции, тут же `extern "C"`

Comment: @user7860670, подробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: @MGNeo, `extern "C"` определяет C-функцию, а не C++, а у C-функций в ассемблерное имя входит только имя функции, а типы аргументов не входят

Comment: @PavelGridin, разве при `export "C++"` в `DLL` попадают сигнатуры функций? Я думал, что нет.